# Mysql: Select all columns and add alias with original column name

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables connected via join. Both tables share some column names. I need to distinguish between those columns. So I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT t1.* AS t1_* , t2.* AS t2_* 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.id=t2.somefield
```

Meaning if in both table is a column "place", the column names should appear in the result list as "t1_place" and "t2_place".

I did not find if this would be possible somehow. The reason is that both tables are rather large so I try to avoid listing all the columns and assigning aliases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to list out all the column names from at least one of the tables and give them aliases.

Comment: you can listing columns table first with `SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table`, after that you save columns record in array with name_table(t1\t2) and then implode to variable (assumed variable is $columns1 and $columns2). so you can running query above `SELECT $columns1, $columns2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.id=t2.somefield`. i hope this helps

Comment: MySQL does not provide this kind of feature. So, question seems too broad...